# How many satellite are used in my every time gps fix?

Tags: android, gps

In my application how can i know how many satellites are used/no. of satellite used for gps fix.

I try below code but it's return zero every time.

```
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event)
{
    //Log.e("Gps_Status", "From on gps status changed");

    if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS) 
    {
        GpsStatus status = m_locationManager._myLocationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
        Iterable<GpsSatellite> sats = status.getSatellites();
        // Check number of satellites in list to determine fix state

        if (sats.iterator().hasNext())
        {
            GpsSatellite gpsSatellite=(GpsSatellite)sats.iterator().next();

            if(gpsSatellite.usedInFix())
            {
                NO_OF_SATELLITE++;

            }

            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(NO_OF_SATELLITE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        //Log.e("Used In FIx", String.valueOf(NO_OF_SATELLITE));
    }
    Log.v("Used In FIx", String.valueOf(NO_OF_SATELLITE));
    // Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(NO_OF_SATELLITE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated .

Thanks
Jalp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey finally I found my solution for get no. of satellite used in gps.

For that you have to use MNEA listener which is provided in android.location package which communicate with satellite and return response in their NMEA standard sentence like $GPGSA.

After getting the response you have to parse the sentence and finally your job is done .

Thanks all for your reviews on that.

Jalp.

Answer (score 2):

To get the no. of satellites the GPS sees I use this code:

```
/**
 * Set the no. of available satellites.
 */
public void updateSats() {
    final GpsStatus gs = this.locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
    int i = 0;
    final Iterator<GpsSatellite> it = gs.getSatellites().iterator();
    while( it.hasNext() ) {
        it.next();
        i += 1;
    }
    this.gpsSatsAvailable = i;
}
```

and in the `GpsStatusListener`:

```
@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(final int event) {
    switch( event ) {
        // ...
    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
        updateSats();
        break;
    }
}
```

I do not check if the sats have been used in the last fix.

Comment: Hey i don't want the count of gps satellite . But i want that how many  no of satellite fix my gps location.

Comment: while( it.hasNext() ) {
        GpsSatellite sat = (GpsSatellite) it.next();
        if (sat.usedInFix()
          i += 1;
    }

Comment: what is gpsSatsAvailable  ?

Comment: Its simply a field to store the result of the satellite count. It is used later to display this number.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simply 3.... [How GPS Phones Work](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gps-phone1.htm)

Comment: Sorry, that is simply wrong. You need at least 3 satellites to get a 2D fix, right, however, the more satellites are visible, the better is the accuracy of the fix.

Comment: If you read your link it clearly says "at least three satellites"